# How to have a different instance of a component in angular

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and a child component. Here is the html from the parent. To summarize

> parent.html

```
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model1"></child-component> //#1
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model2"></child-component> //#2 
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model3"></child-component> //#3
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model4"></child-component> //#4 
<button (click)="removeInput()">Remove #3</button>
```

> parent.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.css']
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: false}) childInteractor: ChildComponent;
removeInput()
{
  this.childInteractor.value = "";
}

}
```

What should I do to make the child component declared in the parent are different instances? because clicking the button removes #1 instead of #3

> child.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

> child.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  value: any;
}
```

Comment: They _are_ different instances. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: This is because the attributes and values of one child component tampers the other. Please help

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, in your parent component you need to use ViewChildren rather than ViewChild. ViewChildren will give you a QueryList of all ChildComponent instances. ViewChild just gives you a reference to the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same 'model' attribute as ngModel

```
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model"></child-component>
```

this 'model' is the same in all 4 children.

please use an array or something, like model[1], model [2]... etc

Answer (score 0):

So... the problem is, you overwrite values in one component, when updating in the sibling, is it correct?
 then what you have to do is not have same input and output in different child-component

```
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model1"></child-component>
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model2"></child-component>
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model3"></child-component>
<child-component [(ngModel)]="model4"></child-component>
```

You should probably read about ngmodel, input and outputs to undersand your own code